# how modify the issue index in smarty

Tags: smarty

I want to change the value of index, how i do this.. 
I wanna to put only four < li >

in each < ul >

```
<ul>

  {section name=pos loop=$post}
         {$smarty.section.pos.index = 1}
              <li>
                <a href="#{$post[pos].titulo}">
                  {$post[pos].titulo}
                </a>
              </li>
              {if $smarty.section.pos.index is div by 4}
                 </ul>
                 <ul>                            
              {/if}
   {/section}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're doing it wrong. Index contains the current array index of the loop starting from 0, you are not supposed to give it a value.

I think that .iteration  ($smarty.section.pos.iteration) is what you're looking for, as it starts at 1